# How to set clang as default compiler using update-alternatives

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gcc, clang

I use Ubuntu 18.04 and I have two gcc/g++ versions which are managed using update-alternatives:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-7 100 --slave /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-7
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.8 50 --slave /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-4.8
```

I can switch compiler using this command:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config gcc
```

I have noticed that I have the following chain for the compiler (gcc-7/g++-7 in this case): `/usr/bin/cc -> /etc/alternatives/cc -> /usr/bin/gcc -> /etc/alternatives/gcc -> /usr/bin/gcc-7
/usr/bin/c++ -> /etc/alternatives/c++ -> /usr/bin/g++ -> /etc/alternatives/g++ -> /usr/bin/g++-7`

I have also installed clang-8 and clang++-8 but `/usr/bin` contains only clang-8 and clang++-8, there is no clang symbolic link. How should I add clang to update-alternatives tools ?

Comment: The `clang` symlink is part of package `clang` and refers to a fixed version. Different maintainer than the gcc packages...

Answer (score 2):

Clang is not a version of GCC, so it cannot be set as an alternative for `/usr/bin/gcc`. Don't try to override this; you will break some programs which require GCC-specific features which aren't available in Clang.

Clang can be set as an alternative for `/usr/bin/cc`. This is the standard way of setting a C compiler, and it should be reasonably safe. (Even so, I wouldn't be surprised if some build processes break due to an assumption that `/usr/bin/cc` on a Linux system is always GCC.)

Comment: I can't use this command: sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/cc cc /usr/bin/clang-8 20 --slave /usr/bin/c++ c++ /usr/bin/clang++-8 because I get the following error: update-alternatives: error: alternative c++ can't be slave of cc: it is a master alternative
I would like to switch clang and clang++ together.